# CKeditor4 with scayt very slow on IE11 and Edge on larger documents

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, scayt

Using ckeditor4 in an Angular 1.6 webapp. Works fine but when enabling SCAYT the whole app/ckeditor get sluggish if you run it on IE11 or Edge. It works quite ok when running in Chrome.

Can be easily reproduced on https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/#document
Use https://www.lipsum.com/ to generate 20 000 bytes of text which really isn't that much and paste it in the editor. Then enable SCAYT, and you will see Edge increasing CPU to 19% and memory alternating from 250 to 340 MB. Try adding some more text to the editor - it is almost impossible.

Any tricks to support SCAYT in IE11 and Edge for CKEditor4?
Any other plugin to recommend?

Answer (score 0):

SCAYT tool checks text by small portions up to 10 words at a time. The larger the document the more time is needed for processing. However, SCAYT shouldn't have affected or blocked the work of CKEditor (adding more text, etc.).

We are able to reproduce the problem with SCAYT performance in IE/Edge using your steps and sample Lorem ipsum text. In your case, the root cause of the SCAYT performance issue is not only the size of the text but and the percentage of misspelled words in this text. For Lorem ipsum text, it is about 99% percent of words that are incorrect, which SCAYT detects and underlines (marks) as incorrect.

If you try to use any real text (even with number of errors) instead of Lorem ipsum, you shouldn't have such dramatic increase of CPU utilization or memory consumption.

Alternatively, you may consider trying another spellcheck plugin provided along with SCAYT in CKEditor – WebSpellChecker Dialog. It is also available under ABC button –> Spell Checking. It is designed to check the large pieces of text at once (in a separate window).

Hope this helps.